# Where is browser.js file in Firefox in RHEL?

Tags: rhel, firefox, browser

I want to modify the browser configuration, and I was unable to find the browser.js file in the installation directory, i.e. `/.Mozilla/Firefox/default/profile/`. Please provide me with the link for browser.js.

Comment: Better tell us what you want to achieve, provide possible solutions that you thought of and leave the people free to come up with working and/or alternative solutions to your problem (because your problems is not finding the `browser.js` file, it is modifying something in Firefox)

Answer (score 2):

You can either use the command `locate` or `find` to "find" this file if you cannot "find" it.

#### Examples

```
$ find / -iname "browser.js"

-or-

$ locate browser.js
```

Both methods will search the entire filesystem. The `find` method will scan the disk in realtime looking for this file, while `locate` will search a database of files that's typically maintained by most Linux systems.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such file part of the Firefox distribution, so there is no `browser.js` file for you to find. You will have to search for another way or another file to implement your changes.